# Backbone.js PUT/DELETE problems with Codeigniter REST server

Tags: codeigniter, rest, backbone.js

NOTE: This question is related to [CodeIgniter-RestServer](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver)

When I call model.save() from backbone the function where the put request is routed doesn't gets any PUT data. Firebug shows right PUT parameters being sent. However $this->put('keyname') always returns false. Which means CI's REST Server can't find PUT data as it should.

On the other hand, If I set:

```
Backbone.emulateJSON = true;
```

I can work, as then Backbone will send all PUT data under a single attribute named "model", using this way $this->put('model'); works

Then the extra effor involved is:

```
$data = json_decode($this->put('model'),true); // to get normal behavior #sucks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into this issue as well and pushed a few changes that fix the problem:
https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver/pull/84

Answer (score 0):

have been through this problem already in the past. Solution to this problem is to use this inside your functions:

```
$data = $this->request->body;
echo $data['id'];
```

Hope that solves it. Cheers!

Comment: Nah still no luck man, I am tried of trying it again n again, so far I am using backbone with EmulateJSON and the work is progressing